# RaventBootstrapper configuration in NServicebus

Tags: c#, nservicebus

I'm trying to make the following NServiceBus Pluralsight training code sample by  Andreas Öhlund to work.

```
public class RavenBootstrapper : INeedInitialization
{
    public void Init()
    {
        Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureComponent<IDocumentStore>(
            () =>
            {
                var store = new DocumentStore
                            {
                                Url = "http://localhost:8080"
                            };

                store.Initialize();
                store.JsonRequestFactory.DisableRequestCompression = true;
                return store;
            }
            , DependencyLifecycle.SingleInstance);

        Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureComponent<IDocumentSession>(
            () =>
            {

                return Configure.Instance.Builder.Build<IDocumentStore>()
                    .OpenSession();
            },
            DependencyLifecycle.InstancePerUnitOfWork);

        Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureComponent<RavenUnitOfWork>(DependencyLifecycle.InstancePerUnitOfWork);

    }
}
```

There were multiple compile errors about obsolete code and I was able to correct most of them but got stock on **Configure.Instance.Builder.Build**... Here's what I have so far:

```
 public class RavenBootstrapper : INeedInitialization
{

        configuration.RegisterComponents(c => c.ConfigureComponent<IDocumentStore>(
           () =>
           {
             var  store = new DocumentStore
                         {
                             Url = "http://localhost:8080"
                         };

               store.Initialize();
               store.JsonRequestFactory.DisableRequestCompression = true;
               return store;
           }
           , DependencyLifecycle.SingleInstance));


        configuration.RegisterComponents(c => 
            c.ConfigureComponent(builder => builder.Build<IDocumentStore>().OpenSession(),DependencyLifecycle.InstancePerUnitOfWork));

        configuration.RegisterComponents(c => c.ConfigureComponent<RavenUnitOfWork>(DependencyLifecycle.InstancePerUnitOfWork));
}
```

1. What is a new equivalent of Builder.Build?
2. Does the rest look good?
3. Would be nice to know where specifically I could find an answer to this in NserviceBus documentation.

Answer (score 2):

There is an overload to Configure.Component that accepts a `Func<IBuilder,TComponent>`

Using this you can change your code to:

```
 configuration.RegisterComponents(c => c.ConfigureComponent<IDocumentStore>(
           () =>
           {
               var store = new DocumentStore
                           {
                               Url = "http://localhost:8080"
                           };

               store.Initialize();
               store.JsonRequestFactory.DisableRequestCompression = true;
               return store;
           }
           , DependencyLifecycle.SingleInstance));

        configuration.RegisterComponents(c => c.ConfigureComponent<IDocumentSession>(
            builder =>
            {

                return builder.Build<IDocumentStore>()
                    .OpenSession();
            },
            DependencyLifecycle.InstancePerUnitOfWork));
```

Comment: I'm still confused by what the first two statements do. I thought the first one configures the document store and puts it into container. Why then the second one builds document store instead of taking it from the container and then using it to open a session?

Comment: By the way, I don't see results of my save stored in Raven DB. Any idea what I can check? My understanding is that the code  "Session.Store(new Order
                     {
                         OrderId = message.OrderId
                     });" in PlaceOrderHandler
                     would result in creating Orders database and some records in it but nothing happens.

Comment: Are you calling session.SaveChanges() any where? (here's how you can do it in v 5 https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.RavenDB/blob/develop/src/NServiceBus.RavenDB/SagaPersister/RavenUnitOfWorkBehavior.cs)

Comment: my bad regarding the config you need both call, I've updated the code example

Comment: I'm calling session.saveChanges in RavenUnitoOfWork class as so: "public void End(Exception ex = null)
        {
            if (ex == null)
                Session.SaveChanges();
        }" I can see the code is executed in the debugger.

Comment: Can you check/log the session id of the raven session to make sure its the same instance?

Answer (score 0):

Mauro Servienti from Particular Software just posted a webinar that you may find helpful.
https://particular-1.wistia.com/medias/q8tdr6mnzz