# RaventBootstrapper configuration in NServicebus 5 Mongodb

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, nservicebus

Basically i want the same solution of this answer with mongodb.

[RaventBootstrapper configuration in NServicebus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26365296/raventbootstrapper-configuration-in-nservicebus)

I did my research and couldn't find it

Comment: How does it relate to NServiceBus? Do you want to use NServiceBus IoC container to register MongoDb dependencies?

Comment: Yes, this is what i want

Comment: RavenDb needs a session to be opened per unit of work. Sessions must be disposed when the work is done, ie when we are talking about NServiceBus, when a handler is finished handling a message. MongoDb discourages you from using connect/disconnect. This makes registration of MongoDb server and database in the DI container quite useless. You might want to do this for your generic repository implementation that shields MongoDb collection. I would suggest using your preferred IoC container and NServiceBus adapter for it.

Comment: Can u please show me how u can do this with ninject? Post it as answer and i will mark it as correct.